# How do you create a function that filters out a specified condition in a column?

Tags: python

This is my dataset

I'm tasked with writing a function that filters out films longer than a certain value.
The function should have two input arguments: the table and the specified running time. In a new table, I can only include films that are two hours or less and sort them by box office gross in descending order. Then I need to print the top 5 elements of the returned table on the screen.

This is what I have so far but the program I'm using says there's errors - "Create the function filter_not_longer_than()"

```
    ["Driving Miss Daisy", 1989, 7.645, 99, ['drama'], 7.5, 145.793296],
    ["Rain Man", 1988, 8.25, 133, ['drama'], 25.0, 354.825435],]


def filter_not_longer_than(data, length_threshold):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        length = row[3]
        if length <= length_threshold:
            result.append(row)
    return result

def print_top5_by_column(data, column, reverse):
    data.sort(key=lambda row: row[column], reverse=reverse)
    print('Title                            | Year  | Rating | Length | Budget | Box office gross  |')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    for row in data[:5]:
        print('{: <35} | {} | {: >7.2f} | {: >5} | {: >6.1f} | {: >6.1f} |'.format(
            row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[5], row[6]))

filter_not_longer_than = filter_not_longer_than(oscar_data, 120)
print_top5_by_column(filter_not_longer_than, 6, True)
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: "Create the function filter_not_longer_than()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parallels$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

your code works perfectly for me. Reproducing here:

```
oscar_data = [["Driving Miss Daisy", 1989, 7.645, 99, ['drama'], 7.5, 145.793296],
                ["Rain Man", 1988, 8.25, 133, ['drama'], 25.0, 354.825435],]

def filter_not_longer_than(data, length_threshold):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        length = row[3]
        if length <= length_threshold:
            result.append(row)
    return result

def print_top5_by_column(data, column, reverse):
    data.sort(key=lambda row: row[column], reverse=reverse)
    print('Title                            | Year  | Rating | Length | Budget | Box office gross  |')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    for row in data[:5]:
        print('{: <35} | {} | {: >7.2f} | {: >5} | {: >6.1f} | {: >6.1f} |'.format(
            row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[5], row[6]))

filter_not_longer_than = filter_not_longer_than(oscar_data, 120)
print_top5_by_column(filter_not_longer_than, 6, True)
```

```
parallels$ python so.py 
Title                            | Year  | Rating | Length | Budget | Box office gross  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Driving Miss Daisy                  | 1989 |    7.64 |    99 |    7.5 |  145.8 |
```

If you're still getting any error, do comment and will be happy to debug together.